# Style SVG stroke with Svelte

Tags: css, svg, tailwind-css, svelte, daisyui

I have the following code in Svelte and I am looking to style the stroke color using a CSS class name (`text-error` and `text-success` instead of `#ff5722` and `#10b759`, respectively).

Is this possible?

I would rather not define the exact color in the component, but let the theme decide through the CSS class (DaisyUI).

New to Svelte, latest versions of everything.

```
<script>
    let isStreaming = false;

    function toggleStreaming() {
        isStreaming = !isStreaming;
    }    
</script>

<div class="someClass">
    <button on:click={toggleStreaming} class="btn {isStreaming ?
    ' text-error':
    ' text-success'}">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             fill="none"
             viewBox="0 0 24 24"
             stroke="{isStreaming ? '#ff5722': '#10b759'}" <!-- this part -->
             class="h-6 mr-2">
            <path stroke-width="2"
                  d="{isStreaming ? 'M18.364 18.364A9 9 0 005.636 5.636m12.728 12.728A9 9 0 015.636 5.636m12.728 12.728L5.636 5.636' : 'M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z'}">
            </path>
        </svg>
        {isStreaming ? 'Kill' : 'Stream'}
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Daisy UI is just a Tailwind plugin you can do this the same way you would in Tailwind: By adding `stroke-current` to the SVG and changing the text color of the button (like you're already doing).

```
<svg ... class="h-6 mr-2 stroke-current">...
```

Here's a Svelte REPL using the Daisy UI CDN and your example with that single change https://svelte.dev/repl/814fd418f164491fbf97d39528cde2d3?version=3.46.3

Comment: Yes!  This is what I was seeking.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class like you do on the button

```
<... class="{isStreaming ? 'text-success' : 'text-error'}">
```

or via the [`class:` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name)  >>
[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8615862ac9dd4db289c821756588516e?version=3.46.3)
(*"...but let the theme decide through the CSS class"* The stroke must be defined on the class - that's the case in the theme? Otherwise there might be variables which might be used...)

```
<svg
  ...
  class:text-success={isStreaming}
  class:text-error={!isStreaming}
  ...
>
```

```
<style>
    .text-success {
        stroke: #10b759;
    }
    .text-error {
        stroke: #ff5722;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the bottom solution wouldn't defer the colors to the theme.  I'd be hard-coding the HEX values in the `<style>` tags.  For example, let's say my theme dictates "blue" as the `text-success` value.  I have to now go to this file and change it.

Comment: @vphilipnyc Sure, if you would set the colors in the classes in the component they wouldn't be overwritten by the theme... I just added the `<style>` block for making the Repl work and to show that the class must have the **stroke** property set and asked if that was the case. In @JHeth 's REPL it looks like as though `.text-success` only sets the color property so using this class couldn't have worked anyway - `.stroke-current` does set it `{ stroke: currentColor;}`

Comment: Yep, agreed.  Thanks for the response